# Javascript - Math.random function returns the same result while called in a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a `function{computerPlay()}` to generate a new random number every time it is called. It returns an item from the array declared at the top. It works how I'd like it to when I test it in the `console`. However, in order for my game to work properly, I've put it in a `for` loop and it keeps returning the same value unless I refresh the page. I can't find an answer anywhere and this is my first question. I'm sure the code is sloppy so please ignore that. Here is the code.

```js
  let playOptionsArray = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
let totalTies = 0;
let playerPoints = 0;
let computerPoints = 0;
let round = 1;

//formats a player's entry so it will match playOptionsArray
  function firstLetterUppercase(string){
    let firstLetter = string.charAt(0);
    let firstLetterCapitalized = firstLetter.toUpperCase();
    let restOfResponse = string.slice(1);
    let formattedResponse = firstLetterCapitalized + restOfResponse;
    return formattedResponse;
  }

//compares player entry to ensure it matches an item on the playOptions array
  function checkPlayerResponse(response){
    if (response === "Rock" || response === "Paper" || response === "Scissors") {
      return response;
    } else {
      return alert("You must choose either 'Rock', 'Paper', or 'Scissor' as your play. Please try again.");
    }
  }

//generates a random option for the computer's play

  function computerPlay() {
    let computerSelection = playOptionsArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*(playOptionsArray.length))];
    return computerSelection;
  }

  let computerSelection = computerPlay();

  function getPlayerSelection() {
    let playerEntry = window.prompt("You are playing the computer in a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors. First player to five points wins. Choose either Rock, Paper, or Scissors as your play", "Rock");
    if (playerEntry != null) {
    let playerEntryLowercase = playerEntry.toLowerCase();
    playerSelection = firstLetterUppercase(playerEntryLowercase);
  } else {
    getPlayerSelection();
  }
    checkPlayerResponse(playerSelection);
    return playerSelection;
  }

  let playerSelection = getPlayerSelection;

//emulates a single round of rock paper scissor
  function singleRound(){
    if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors"){
      alert('You have won this round. The computer chose ' + computerSelection + '.');
      playerPoints++;
      round++;
    } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper"){
      alert('You have won this round. The computer chose ' + computerSelection + '.');
      playerPoints++;
      round++
    } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Rock"){
      alert('You have won this round. The computer chose ' + computerSelection + '.');
      playerPoints++;
      round++
    } else if (playerSelection === computerSelection){
      alert('You have tied this round. The computer chose ' + computerSelection + '.');
      totalTies++;
    } else {
      alert('Something went wrong. Refresh the page.')
    }
  }

  function updateScore() {
    document.getElementById("player-points").innerHTML = playerPoints;
    document.getElementById("round").innerHTML = round;
    document.getElementById("computer-points").innerHTML = computerPoints;
    document.getElementById("total-ties").innerHTML = totalTies;
  }

//keeps track of player points and ends when a player gets 5 points
 function game() {
    for (round = 0; computerPoints < 5 && playerPoints < 5; round) {
      getPlayerSelection();
      computerPlay();
      singleRound();
      updateScore();
      }
  }

game();
```

Comment: Obligatory random number cartoon http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: In `game` you're not doing anything with the returned value from `computerPlay`. Is that intentional?

Comment: You keep calling `computerPlay` but your round scoring checks a global variable `computerSelection` you only set once (the local `computerSelection` inside the function shadows the global). Congratulations! You just learned that side-effects are evil. Burned hands teach best and whatnot.

Comment: Also `let playerSelection = getPlayerSelection;` should be `let playerSelection = getPlayerSelection();` if you want it to do anything.

Comment: Please note, for future questions, that an **MVE** should consist of clean (*Not Sloppy*), easy to read code only.  Anything not necessary to address the specific issue your question is asking, or to provide a running example, should be deleted.  This helps us help you, and *want* to help you.  Sometimes it also reveals the issue itself.  Welcome to SO, I hope your issue gets resolved. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and **[MVE: Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned value from `computerPlay` isn't stored anywhere in the loop. (should note this is happening with your `playerSelection` too). Try

```js
for (round = 0; computerPoints < 5 && playerPoints < 5; round) {
  playerSelection = getPlayerSelection();
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  singleRound();
  updateScore();
}
```

Edit: @kavakava's answer provides some insight into why this is the case.

Comment: Although this certainly works, it might be best to explain to the OP what a less error-prone method than updating a global might look like.

Comment: @JaredSmith I realized shortly after writing my answer that there was indeed a better way by modifying the loop. Please refresh and check my answer again and let me know if there is still an issue. Thanks

Comment: A better way would be to use the return values and ditch the global entirely: `singleRound(computerPlay(), getPlayerSelection())` with `singleRound` modified to take those as parameters instead of checking global state.

Comment: Agreed that global variables should generally be avoided, and if it were up to me I'd take your approach. For the sake of answering OP's question, however, I think I will keep this answer to explain why his code isn't working and leave better program design for him to learn another day (or from y'all in the comments :) )

Comment: If you don't teach him/her now, he/she will be back tomorrow with the same problems.

Comment: I went ahead and spelled it out in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a combination of two well-known sources of error: [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) and [global state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

In JavaScript, each function creates a new scope:

```
var foo = 3;
function() { var bar = 2; };
console.log(foo + bar); // ERROR, bar is local to the function
```

Inner scopes can access stuff from outside (you can still see `foo` inside the function) but not the other way around. Shadowing is what happens when you declare the same name in an inner scope as an outer:

```
var foo = 3;
(function() {
  var foo = 2;
  console.log(foo); // 2
})();
console.log(foo); // 3 the outer foo isn't change by the inner.
```

If you omit the declaration (i.e. var, let, const) then the program searches up through scopes to find it:

```
var foo = 3;
(function() {
  foo = 2; // will reach up to the outer foo
})();
console.log(foo); // 2
```

If you aren't mixing scopes this way, you can't have this problem. The easiest way to solve it is to prevent it from happening. Modify your `singleRound` function to take two parameters:

```
function singleRound(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
  // everything else the same
}
```

Now when you call it in the loop:

```
singleRound(computerPlay(), getPlayerSelection());
```

When you use the return values you can't go wrong as easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
function computerPlay() {
    let computerSelection = playOptionsArray[
            Math.floor(Math.random()*(playOptionsArray.length))
         ]; // Line #1

     return computerSelection;
}

let computerSelection = computerPlay(); // Line: #2
```

This seems to be your problem. The reason it was never changing was because you never changed it. remove the 'let' on line 1 and you should be all set. You were returning the var in computerPlay, not the global.